# Cplex API in matlab failed to write solution in .sol files

Tags: xml, matlab, api, export, cplex

I am using cplex api in Matlab and yalmip to solve a simple Lp problem. After solving, I want to save the solution in files. The solution is in the cplex objects.
According to the help files, the method "**cplex.writeSolution('min_test.sol')**" will do the job. But when I call it, it shows that:

Error using cplexlink1290
CPLEX Error  1217: No solution exists.

I cannot find where is the problem. Anybody knows why?

### The following is the source codes I used

```
clc,clear

year_w = 25;
discount = 0.08;
c_inv_w_raw = 6700/10; 
year_present = 11;

c_inv_w = c_inv_w_raw/year_present;
c_op_g = 0.025 * 8760; 

l_t = 1000; % MW
wind_data = 0.24; % p.u.
p_gc_max = 800; % MW
p_wc_max = -1; % MW 

%% 
p_wc = sdpvar();
p_w = sdpvar();
p_g = sdpvar();

c_inv = p_wc * c_inv_w;
c_op = p_g * c_op_g;

obj = c_inv + c_op;

%% 
cons = [];
cons_name_list=cell(0,1);

cons = [cons,(p_w + p_g == l_t):'PB'];
cons_name_list = cat(1, cons_name_list,{'PB'});

cons = [cons,(p_w <= wind_data * p_wc):'w_u'];
cons_name_list = cat(1, cons_name_list,{'w_u'});

cons = [cons,(p_w >= 0):'w_l'];
cons_name_list = cat(1, cons_name_list,{'w_l'});

if p_gc_max>0
    cons = [cons,(0<=p_g <= p_gc_max):'g_ul'];
    cons_name_list = cat(1, cons_name_list,{'g_ul'});
end
if p_wc_max>0
    cons = [cons,(0<=p_wc <= p_wc_max):'wc_u'];
    cons_name_list = cat(1, cons_name_list,{'wc_u'});
end

fg_calbycplex =true;

%% 
if fg_calbycplex
    disp('cplex');
    [model,recoverymodel,~,internalmodel] = export(cons,obj,sdpsettings('solver','cplex')); 
    model.A   = [model.Aineq;model.Aeq];
    model.lhs  = [-inf(size(model.Aineq,1),1); model.beq];
    model.rhs   = [model.bineq; model.beq];
    model.idxeq = size(model.bineq,1) + (1:size(model.beq,1));

    cplex = Cplex('GTEP');
    cplex.Model.sense = 'minimize';
    cplex.Model.obj   = model.f;
    cplex.Model.lb    = -inf(size(model.Aineq,2),1);
    cplex.Model.ub    = inf(size(model.Aineq,2),1);
    cplex.Model.A     = model.A;
    cplex.Model.lhs   = model.lhs;
    cplex.Model.rhs   = model.rhs;

    tic
    % cplex.DisplayFunc=[] %@disp
    cplex.solve(); 
    toc

    assign(recover(recoverymodel.used_variables),cplex.Solution.x); 

end
```

> > cplex.Solution

ans =

```
      status: 1
statusstring: 'optimal'
        time: 0.0160
     dettime: 0.0028
      objval: 2.2596e+05
           x: [3x1 double]
      method: 2
        dual: [5x1 double]
       basis: [1x1 struct]
 reducedcost: [3x1 double]
          ax: [5x1 double]
```

> > cplex.writeSolution('min_test.sol')
> > Error using cplexlink1290
> > CPLEX Error  1217: No solution exists.

Error in Cplex/writeSolution

Error in Cplex/subsref

Comment: Were you able to reproduce this issue with a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you could provide us with? If yes, please do so, and we will help you. So far, we understand that your model did not converge with the input data and parameters; this is why it cannot write a solution.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I forgot a function. I have updated the codes, which just sets "year_present = 11". I can run it on my computer standalone and CPLEX can obtain an optimal solution. Still, I cannot export the solution.